# Procedure when user creates several questions about the same topic (with slight differences)

Tags: discussion

Is this OK?

An example is [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6944996/uplnypan#top-posts). See the topics regarding [AlarmManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980267/android-creating-alarm-clock-with-alarmmanager).

They have several questions about the same topic. Each question is an iteration of the same topic.

Shouldn't this be handled in the same question via edits?

Comment: Sounds like you've hit a help vampire.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So long as they're not the *same* question, then I don't *really* see a problem with it, personally.  The amount of questions they've asked in a short period of time indicates to me that some form of rate limiting hasn't quite been reached yet, but I'm going to have to trust that the system catches what it needs to catch from that angle.

Allowing a user to iteratively edit their question would be detrimental as well, since they run the risk of invalidating existing answers.  In those circumstances, it's more preferable to let them ask new questions even if the topics are *related*.

To that end, let's unpack some of these questions.

- [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39944119/android-java-make-notification-at-specified-day-in-week) is essentially the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39945018/android-alarm-manager-runs-every-day), although the latter now has an upvoted answer.
- [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39968484/java-android-alarm-manager-triggers-immediately) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39976530/creating-fully-working-alarm-clock) effectively duplicate [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39978322/alarmmanager-with-calendar-object-android-java), which you've answered.  Easy enough to close as a duplicate.

The OP definitely should be doing more research into their problems and experimenting more with their solutions in this case, but the bigger thing to call out is that the questions which are essentially asking the same thing with the same code (strong indicator) should be closed and the questions which have an open answer should be favored.  I've taken that according action since I have a gold badge in Java (and they've thankfully tagged their questions with [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java)).

Comment: Wonderful, well explained and very nicely cleaned up. A big green tick for you.

Answer (score 5):

> Shouldn't this be handled in the same question via edits?

Without inspecting the links you've been giving, there's a problem with iterated question edits that make the question a moving target. This is prone to invalidate existing answers and not well appreciated.